# Rails dynamic link_to's

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, link-to

I have a view that has the following ruby code that I want to use to create a dynamic link in my application:

```
<% @customer.jobs.each do |job| %>
  <%= link_to job.id, job %>
<% end %>
```

This throws an undefined method error for job_path, which makes sense since my jobs_controller show method is empty:

```
def show
end
```

Here are my routes:

```
resources :customers do
  resources :jobs
end
```

My question is - how do I set up the method in the controller to make my link_to work on the view page?

Essentially, I am pulling an item from the DB, and then trying to create a link to the corresponding view using the DB item.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have

```
<%= link_to job.id, job %>
```

Here second option specifies your url or path helper. **You are getting this error because there is no job_path helper for your routes**

*To check all the url or path helpers do rake routes in your terminal. It will give you output which looks something like*

```
Prefix       Verb   URI Pattern                                     Controller#Action

customer_job GET    /customers/:customer_id/jobs/:id(.:format)      jobs#show
```

So replace your link with

```
<%= link_to job.id, customer_job_path(@customer,job) %>
```

**UPDATE:**

Referring to your comment:

> @customer is an instance variable of your Customer model which you would have defined in   your controller action(since you are using it in your view). Instance variables defined in your controller action are automatically available for its view. For details you should read [**docs**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/)

Comment: customer_job_path(@customer, job)

Comment: @TiagoFarias it'll be job actually :)

Comment: @TiagoFarias When using customer_job_path(@customer, @job) I'm getting no route matches and it says I am missing required keys [:id].  I am guessing this is because I have not initialized customer or job in the controller?

Comment: @TiagoFarias - Tiago for the win again!  Thank you so much.

Comment: @Mandeep thank you for the explanation, I see where I went wrong now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use shallow resources

```
resources :customers, shallow: true do
  resources :jobs
end
```

and then use the `job_path` url helper:

```
<%= link_to job.id job_path(job) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Run

> rake routes

you will probably find that the route is actually something like `customer_job_path`

To work with this you will need to change the link_to to

```
  <%= link_to job.id, customer_job_path(@customer, job) %>
```

Comment: That is exactly right and worked - can I ask a learning question - what information is contained within @customer and where is it being derived from in this case?

Comment: No worries, in this case @customer is being defined in (im assuming) your customer controllers show method. Most likely it will be something like 

`@customer = Customer.find params[:id]`

which finds the Customer model that you click on based on the id passed in by anther `link_to customer.id, customer`

A good way to experiment with this is to use a gem call pry `gem 'pry'` which is an awesome debugging tool that allows you to jump into the code via console whereever you enter `binding.pry`

So in summary @customer contains a Customer model

Comment: @DustinJames updated my answer for a bit of explanation.

Comment: @ob264 Thanks for the gem recommendation and the explanation, that helps.